# ggplot2 ecdf faceting for subsets + overall ecdf in each panel

Tags: r, ggplot2, ecdf

I have a data set with a continuous variable and a factor with ***n*** levels.

I'd like to plot an empirical cumulative distribution function for each level separately plus an overall ecdf in each of the panels. The point is to compare the subsets' (levels') ecdf with the overall (full data set).

Plotting each of the ecdfs in one panel is easy (using "diamonds" data set as an example):

```
ggplot(diamonds) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(x=carat, colour = color)) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(x=carat), lwd=1, linetype="dotted")
```

But when I try using the faceting option to separte the levels into panels

```
ggplot(diamonds) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(x=carat, colour = color)) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(x=carat), lwd=1, linetype="dotted") + 
  facet_wrap(~color, ncol=4)
```

Instead of ***n*** panels with a subset's ecdf and an overall ecdf (dotted) I get each subset's ecdf plotted twice.

I'm sure I'm missing something *obvious*. Feel free to point me to relevant question if I'm duplicating someone else's.

Comment: @beginneR In what way? As far as I know, `facet_grid` is just a more structured way of faceting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another hacky solution, remove the `color` variable from the `diamonds` dataset when plotting the overall ecdf:

```
ggplot(diamonds) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(x=carat, colour = color)) + 
  stat_ecdf(data=diamonds[, names(diamonds) != "color"], aes(x=carat), lwd=1, linetype="dotted") + 
  facet_wrap(~color, ncol=4)
```